# User can change admin permissions

Tags: mongodb, express

So basically I'm working on this project, and I have a route so users can change some of their settings, The problem is that the user can even change his permissions, admin perms etc.

```
router.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    const token = req.cookies.session;
    if (!token) res.redirect('/Login');
    const Player_ID = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    console.log(Player_ID);
    const PlayerID = Player_ID._id;    
    try {
        if(req.body.password || req.body.username || req.body.id || req.body.email || req.body.views || req.body.isVerified || req.body.admin ) res.status(401).json({ok: false});
        const changeAll = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(PlayerID, {...req.body });
        res.status(200).json({ok: true});
    } catch (error) {
    }
})
```

Comment: If you have role in your project, you can create two different route, admin/:id and user/:id and set the role in the token, and create a middleware, in that middleware you can check the access who send a request

Comment: well it's not the normal role, just added a thing in database where 
admin: {
default:false
}

Comment: visit this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-constant

Comment: i would use this, but later on i'm gonna make a route so user can change his email and username. so this will be a temporary fix, but not a long one.

Comment: Before updating you should check what keys are sent to the update function

Comment: `let objPlayer ={ name :req.body.name....}` and `await User.findByIdAndUpdate(PlayerID, objPlayer )`;

Comment: isn't this exactly what i'm doing? :D

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I advise you to read the how to ask a good question [(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)]

Comment: i tried your method but it's not working. one of them changes but the other is "null" ;c

Comment: added schema to your question

Comment: what do you mean by added schema to your question.